# How can I do this cURL code in node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, url, curl, put

I have a problem in how to make this code from cURL in node.js.

`curl -X PUT "URL" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer Authorization code" \
     -d "power=on"`

Comment: You could use the built in nodejs `http` module or many other modules out there for making http requests

Answer (score 0):

You can run any arbitrary command in node.js using built-in [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) module:

Example code:

```
const {execSync} = require('child_process');
const command = `curl -X PUT "https://google.com"  -H "Authorization: Bearer Authorization code" -d "power=on"`;

execSync(command).toString();
```

By the way, this is not the best way. In general, you should avoid synchronous calls, as they block event loop. And in your particular example, it's better to make PUT HTTP requests either using built-in `http` module (as suggested in comments) or choosing any [http module on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=http)

Comment: @SGE59 this code will work if you have node.js version 4 or above. You can play around here https://runkit.com/holubiev/58f7dd06c59f1f0011952fce